# Can Fritzing automatically position my components on a PCB?

Tags: pcb-design

Thanks for looking. I am new to Fritzing and think it's autoroute capabilities are great!

That said, I am wondering if there is a way to auto-position the components in the PCB view in order to get the best layout and routing of traces?

For the particular board I am working on, placement of the components is not important but I am constrained by a fairly small pcb size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The auto-position of components is a feature **NOT** available in Fritzing and, for what it matters, also in many other EDA tools.

Only the most advanced tools provide such a feature and Fritzing, while being a great tool, cannot be listed among the most advanced ones.